# SSMS 2014 does not launch Graphical Execution Plan from clicking hyper-linked query plan - ShowPlanXML

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms, execution-plan, dmv, showplan

I am working with an older version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014. I run the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Q.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan( qs.plan_handle ) Q
WHERE Q.dbid = DB_ID( 'Northwind' )
```

When I click on one of the hyperlinked query_plans (ShowPlanXML=...), SSMS 2014 opens the link in a new text window in XML format. As I understand it, SSMS is supposed to open the link as a graphical execution plan.

Is there any way to configure SSMS to automatically open the ShowPlanXML link as a graphical execution plan without third party software and without updating the version I have of SSMS 2014?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure the System Registry contains the correct file-extension-mapping for .sqlplan files.

Open the Registry Editor, navigate to the following key:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.SQLPlan
```

Confirm the `(Default)` value contains something like:

```
ssms.SQLPlan.14.0
```

(the version number might be different for SSMS 2014).

This is a screenshot of Registry Editor showing the key and value:

[image]

You'll also need to ensure the following value is set correctly:

[image]

When I say "correctly", I mean appropriately for your system.  If this approach doesn't work, I'd try simply re-installing SSMS 2014.  Of course, I'd actually recommend installing the latest version of SSMS, v18, which is available for *free* [directly from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).